# complex valued function that is real for real arguments but also has complex roots?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

I'm looking for a continuous function, polynomial or transcendental, whatever, that takes real values when its argument is real, but has at least one pair of complex valued roots with non-zero imaginary part. The Hardy Z function would fit this description, but it isn't known to have any complex roots. Does anyone have any examples?

Thanks

Comment: Would a quadratic with negative discriminant satisfy your needs?

Comment: Like $f(z) = z^2+1$

Comment: that also works.. yes, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f = e^{x}- e^{-x}$
Observe that

$$f(i \pi ) = e^{i \pi} - e^{- i \pi} = -1 - (-1) = 0 $$
So there is your complex root.

Also observe that $f$ is real on all real arguments.

(curious fact i realized after that answer)

$$ f = 2 \sinh(x) $$

---

I realized you said "pair" of roots.

So in that case observe that $k i \pi  \ \forall  \ k \in \mathbb{N}$ is a root here (i.e. $...-2i\pi,-i \pi, 0, i \pi, 2 i \pi ... $)

Thus we have infinitely many such pairs of roots.